# AutoLayout and AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a UIView

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *previewView;
```

`previewView` will ultimately display the preview of what is going on in my camera on my iPhone using the following preview layer.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer;
```

I have constraints set up on my `previewView` in storyboards and therefore am running into the following issue.

```
self.previewLayer.frame = self.previewView.bounds; // This doesn't work
self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize;
[self.previewView.layer addSublayer:self.previewLayer];
```

`previewLayer` gets added to the previewView subLayer, but it does not show in the right parameters (width and height). I think this is due to using constraints on autolayout.

How would I fix this?

Update: I also tried the following:

```
self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
CALayer *rootLayer = [previewView layer];
rootLayer.frame = self.previewView.bounds;
[rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[self.previewLayer setFrame:[rootLayer bounds]];
[rootLayer addSublayer:self.previewLayer];
```

And it appears to show like this: http://cl.ly/image/3T3o0O1E3U17

Getting close, but still very much off.

Comment: I have a similar problem. My camera picture looks very similar to yours, i.e. there is a big empty bar on the right side. So far, I have figured out that this problem only occurs for me when using Auto-Layout.

Answer (score 18):

Okay, I solved it.

The problem is that when you use autolayout, the frames/bounds of your `UIViewController`'s subviews can change *after* you have set up your `previewLayer`, without the `previewLayer` itself being updated accordingly! This is because the layout of `CALayer`s is solely controlled by one's own code (see also this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27735617/623685).

To solve this, you have to override the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of your `UIViewController` to update the `previewLayer`'s position and bounds (and possibly others) every time the subviews' layout changes.

---

In the following, I will describe how I solved it in detail:

My case was actually a bit more complicated, because I am using the OpenCV iOS framework 2.4.9. Here, the preview layer is created and managed by an OpenCV class called `CvVideoCamera`. Therefore I had to create a subclass of `CvVideoCamera`, to which I added the following method:

```
- (void)updatePreviewLayer
{
    self.customPreviewLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.parentView.frame.size.width, self.parentView.frame.size.height);
    [self layoutPreviewLayer];
}
```

Explanation: `parentView` is a UIView you pass to `CvVideoCamera` in order to specify where the preview layer should be positioned and how big it should be. `customPreviewLayer` is the preview layer managed by CvVideoCamera. And `layoutPreviewLayer` is a method that basically updates the layer's position: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/highgui/src/cap_ios_video_camera.mm#L211

Then I simply called this method from my UIViewController like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidLayoutSubviews");
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.myCameraView updatePreviewLayer];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main idea is the same - when using `Autolayout`, the frame of the preview layer needs to be set after all view constraints have been applied. The `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method is used for this - same as in the original answer but without complications of using any frameworks other than the Apple's `AVFoundation`.

The following code is based on an Apple's sample ([AVCam-iOS: Using AVFoundation to Capture Images and Movies](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCam/Listings/Objective_C_AVCam_AVCamCameraViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112-Objective_C_AVCam_AVCamCameraViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_7)). But the code was modified to use `updateViewConstraints` method to programmatically set all constraints instead of the Storyboard approach used in the sample. Relevant fragments are shown below:

```
@interface QRScannerViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) UIView *previewView;

@end

@implementation QRScannerViewController
{
    AVCaptureSession *_captureSession;
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *_captureVideoPreviewLayer;
    dispatch_queue_t _sessionQueue;
}

#pragma mark - Lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view addSubview:self.previewView];

    _captureSession = [AVCaptureSession new];
    _captureVideoPreviewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_captureSession];
    _captureVideoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

    _sessionQueue = dispatch_queue_create("av_session_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

    dispatch_async(_sessionQueue, ^{
        [self configureCaptureSession];
    });

    [self.previewView.layer addSublayer:_captureVideoPreviewLayer];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (_isCaptureDeviceConfigured) {
        [_captureSession startRunning];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    _captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.previewView.bounds;
}

#pragma mark - getters / initializers

- (UIView *)previewView
{
    if (_previewView) {
        return _previewView;
    }
    _previewView = [UIView new];
    _previewView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _previewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    return _previewView;
}

- (void)configureCaptureSession
{
    [_captureSession beginConfiguration];

    // Code omitted, only relevant to the preview layer is included. See the Apple's sample for full code.
    ...
    _captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = initialVideoOrientation;
    ...
}

#pragma mark - Autolayout

- (void)updateViewConstraints
{
    [self.previewView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor constant:0.0].active = YES;
    [self.previewView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerYAnchor constant:-40.0].active = YES;
    [self.previewView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:300].active = YES;
    [self.previewView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.previewView.widthAnchor constant:0.0].active = YES;

    [super updateViewConstraints];
}
```