# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer Not Filling Bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I have a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and I want to fill that to the bounds of my UIView. It doesn't seem to be working correctly, though. It only shows on around 3/4 of the screen.

```
CGRect bounds=self.previewView.layer.bounds;
self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
self.previewLayer.bounds = bounds;
self.previewLayer.position=CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds));
[self.previewView.layer addSublayer:self.previewLayer];
```

Image: http://cl.ly/image/1Y441f3B2d1m

Answer (score 6):

It's likely that your container view get's resized at some point after the preview layer has been added to it, and since CALayer's don't have autoresizing masks or autolayout, it doesn't update it's frame, you'll need to do it manually

Comment: Mind clariyfying a bit?

Comment: When a viewController is created, it's view frame will usually be different than it's final frame. Usually it's created at iPhone4 resolution (320*480), and then at some point during it's lifecycle (before being shown), it's resized to it's actual resolution (in your case 375*667. It's likely that you set the previewLayer frame before the resizing happened, as I can see it's size is 320*320, but because layers don't resize themselves automatically, it will stay at that size until you change it.

Comment: What you'll need to do is update it's bounds and position either in -viewWillLayoutSubviews if you are in a UIViewController or -layoutSubviews if you are in a UIView